# error: (type 1): cannot open file for reading 'ugmm8a.pfb' in LaTeX (font depreciated)

Tags: lua, latex

I have been trying to compile my latex code in overleaf.com, but it keeps giving the errors as follows, and it does not point in which line of the code the error is located in:

[image: Error Message]

It seems like a font issue there and here is the raw log of the error:

```
    {/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/ly1/texnansi.enc}
! error:  (type 1): cannot open file for reading 'ugmm8a.pfb'
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I need to solve this error to get my output document.

Comment: Better suited to http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The urw-garamond fonts works just fine with texlive2021, you just need the `ugmr8a.pfb` from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond

[image]

https://www.overleaf.com/read/cmvfrqrkrnrq

(... however it might give better results not to use such a legacy font if you're already using lualatex, overleaf has many good fonts installed https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the quick answer and your time. This method works too. In fact, it kept asking for the following 3 files as I kept adding each: 'ugmm8a.pfb', 'ugmr8a.pfb' & 'ugmri8a.pfb'. And all the files were available in the link you sent above. And after adding them to the root folder, the code just ran with the 2021 compiler version.

I am new to posting questions on StackOverflow. Impressed by the quick response.

Comment: @DEEPAKS.V. You're welcome! (it was not that quick, it would have been much faster if there had been a [mre] in the question so I didn't have to create a test document :) )

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem by myself.

Turns out the solution was just to **change the Compiler (TeX Live) version of the overleaf.com project from 2021 to 2016** (since the 'ugmm8a.pfb' font got depreciated in the later version).

Hence I had to press the Menu option in the Top Left of my project, and then change the "TeX Live version" from 2021 to 2016 as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

And after this one change when I recompiled, my document was successfully outputted without any errors.

As an additional info to people who are facing similar issues check this post by overleaf.com on how to add new fonts that do not exist on their server to your project: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX#Using_fonts_not_installed_on_Overleaf.27s_servers:_Google_Fonts_example